# Files From Upload Modal Not Being Passed

Tags: asp.net-core, file-upload, bootstrap-modal

I have a BootStrap Modal Popup that I want to use for selecting and uploading a file. The pop-up works in all respects EXCEPT it is not passing the selected file to the underlying controller. Here is the form:

```
<!--Modal Body Start-->
<div class="modal-content">

<!--Modal Header Start-->
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Upload File</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
</div>
<!--Modal Header End-->
<form asp-action="FileUpload" asp-controller="Attachment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
        <div>
            <p>Upload a file using this form:</p>
            <input type="file" name="file" />
        </div>

        <!--Modal Footer Start-->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success relative" id="btnSubmit" data-save="modal" value="Upload">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            &nbsp;
        </div>

    </div> <!--Modal Footer End-->
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

    });
</script>

<!--Modal Body End-->
```

Here is the action in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult FileUpload(IFormFile file)
    {
        //DO something with the file
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(string issueid)
    {
        ViewBag.id = issueid;
        return PartialView("_UploadFile");
    }
```

The action gets called but the "file" variable is NULL.

I have the following markup & script on the MAIN page the pop-up originates from:

```
       <div id="modal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

 <a href="@Url.Action("UploadFile", new { controller = "Attachment", issueid = Model.IssueData.issueId  })" class="modal-link btn btn-success">Upload Files</a>

<script>
    $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function () {
        var actionUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(actionUrl).done(function (data) {
            $('body').find('.modal-content').html(data);
        });
        $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
        $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.relative', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        var dataToSend = form.serialize();
        $.post(actionUrl, dataToSend).done(function (data) {
            $('body').find('.modal-content').html(data);
        });
    })

    $('body').on('click', '.close', function () {
        $('body').find('#modal-container').modal('hide');
    });

    $('#CancelModal').on('click', function () {
        return false;
    });

    $("form").submit(function () {
        if ($('form').valid()) {
            $("input").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To upload form data with a file you have to use a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object.
Also, you have to use $.ajax, as $.past cannot handle the FormData object

```
$('body').on('click', '.relative', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
    var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
    var dataToSend = new FormData(form[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: actionUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataToSend,
        processData: false, //prevent jQuery from trying to serialize the FormData object
        contentType: false, // prevents jQuery from setting the default content type
        success: function(data){
            $('body').find('.modal-content').html(data);
        }
    });        
})
```

Comment: Replacing the $('body').on('click', '.relative', function (e)  I have with the one you have breaks some existing code. When I add in the $.ajax instead of the $.post prevents validation on another modal pop-up on the same page. Also, how is the formdata object different from <form asp-action="FileUpload" asp-controller="Attachment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">? In Core this is what i use to pass from data back to the controller.